# How to insert only 'message' from JSON response to database in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

I Have this code

```
$data = Http::withHeaders([
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.env('OPENAI_API_KEY'),
                  ])
                  ->post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", [
                    "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                    'messages' => [
                        [
                           "role" => "user",
                           "content" => $search
                       ]
                    ],
                    'temperature' => 0.5,
                    "max_tokens" => 200,
                    "top_p" => 1.0,
                    "frequency_penalty" => 0.52,
                    "presence_penalty" => 0.5,
                    "stop" => ["11."],
                  ])
                  ->json();

                  return response()->json($data['choices'][0]['message'], 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

how can insert into Laravel database only $data['message']

Thanks in advance

echo $data['message'];

Comment: By this [api response](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/response-format), you just do: save() to `$data['choices'][0]['message']['content']` is this what you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

By the api docs of openai with a [response](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/response-format) you need to save with:

```
$data['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
```